# jQuery expand unique sub meu

Tags: jquery

My project has some li elements which their class name is same (.expanded)

my goal is when user hit tab key ,then the hidden sub menu under li.expaned show up.

now the problem is when I hit tab key, all the sub menus show up.How to show it one by one?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.expanded').keyup(function (e) {
        $('.expanded').each(function () {
            console.log('keyup called');
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

            if (code == '9') {
                //jQuery(this).children('.side_menu_sub li ul').css("display", "block");
                $(this).children('.side_menu_sub li ul').css("display", "block");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Petr Marek,thanks, but don't work

Comment: Is the event firing? You shouldn't bind `keyup` to `li` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).find('> .side_menu_sub > li > ul').css("display", "block");
```

You can always check which elements you selected with `console.log`ing them. Just play around with the css selector.

Also, it's a good practice to store reused jQuery objects in variables. You should use `on` instead of the specific functions. The result would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    expanded = $('.expanded');
    expanded.on('keyup', function (e) {
        expanded.each(function () {
            console.log('keyup called');
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

            if (code == '9') {
                //jQuery(this).children('.side_menu_sub li ul').css("display", "block");
                $(this).find('> .side_menu_sub > li > ul').css("display", "block");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks,but this scripts is not work,however I learned how to use "On" instead of functions.I just solved by myself

Comment: my self solution :~change second $('.expanded') to be $(this)